# Show following series diverges $1/(log2)^p + 1/(log3)^p + 1/(log4)^p ... + 1/(logn)^p +...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that following infinite series diverges for $p \ge 0$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{(\log 2)^p} +\frac{1}{(\log 3)^p} +\frac{1}{(\log 4)^p} +\cdots +\frac{1}{(\log n)^p}+\cdots$

Comment: When $n$ large enough $\dfrac{1}{(\log n)^p} \geq \dfrac{1}{n}$

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle can this be donw using other tests than comparison tests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(\forall x\geqslant1,\ \log x\leqslant x)\implies(\forall x\geqslant1,\  \log x\leqslant px^{1/p})\implies\forall n\geqslant2,\ \frac1{(\log n)^p}\geqslant\frac{1/p^p}n$$

Comment: Sir how $log x≤px^{1/p}$?

Answer (score 1):

Since:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\log(1+n)^p}\geq\frac{N}{\log(N+1)^p}$$
divergence for is trivial.